# How can I create a HashMap in Rust that can go 4 to 5 times deep with values that are maps?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I need to create a `HashMap` with values that are `HashMap`s and possibly containing values that could also be HashMaps, and this can go 4 to 5 times deep. For example;

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let entry: HashMap<String, T> = HashMap::new();
}
```

T can be a `HashMap` that contains other `HashMap`s as values and so on. Keys are always `String`s and leaf values can be of various types. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are leaf values of all the same type and keys are `String`?

Comment: `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Whatever>>>`?

Comment: @AlexLarionov I've edited the question to reflect your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Leaf values can be of various types"* - that sounds like an `enum` to me.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum Value {
    Leaf(String), // or whatever types they can be
    Nested(HashMap<String, Value>),
}

fn main() {
    let entry: HashMap<String, Value> = HashMap::new();
}
```

Comment: But how does it make leaf values of various types? They're the same (`String`) in this case

Comment: `Leaf(String)` is just a stand-in variant since OP didn't specify what other types they could be. Different enum variants would be used for the different leaf types.

Comment: I just thought it's like a `json!` with arbitrary structure and leaf types